# How to make action controller thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

In my MVC 3 application, i need to call an action controller every 5 minutes.
In this action controller, i will read and parse an XML file.
So when i have a lot of clients that are calling the action method at the same time, i will get IO exception. How can i avoid this problem and make my action call thread safe.
my controller action looks like below:

```
public PartialViewResult _warningsView(string containerId)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("_warningsView");
    var myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
    myXslTrans.Load(@"E:/web/data/xml/alert.xslt");
    myXslTrans.Transform(@"E:/.../alert.xml", @"E:/.../TransAlert.xml");
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(warnings));
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"E:/.../TransAlert.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        warnings result = (warnings)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
        return new Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult
        {
            RenderMode = RenderMode.AddTo,
            ContainerId = containerId,
            Model = result.warningList,
            WrapByScriptTag = false
        };
    }
}
```

i forgot to mention to error:

```
[IOException: The process cannot access the file 'E:\web\data\xml\TransAlert.xml' because it is being used by another process.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +10527069
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1305
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +60
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync) +54
   System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings.CreateWriter(String outputFileName) +155
   System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(String outputFileName, XmlWriterSettings settings) +23
   System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(String inputUri, String resultsFile) +91
   WIS_3_0.Controllers.HomeController._warningsView(String containerId) in C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\wis30\WIS_3_0\Controllers\HomeController.cs:92
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +180
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +214
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +253
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +253
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +324
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +106
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +91
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +48
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514928
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: What's the exact exception you get? Please post the result of `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the IO exception? And what does it say?

Comment: Does this file change over time?

Comment: Why are you transforming out to a file?  Use one of the overloads that works with streams and use a `MemoryStream`

Comment: @JohnSaunders the exception was added to the post. thanks

Comment: @MarcelN. the post was updated with the exception details

Comment: @lan yes this file change every 5 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple requests writing to the same file! If you insist on using a file for output, then you should write to a temp file (unique file name each request).

Even better would be to write to a MemoryStream.

Comment: how can multiple requests share the temp file name or the MemoryStream? We are using mvc controllers, so each client request will be not remember other requests

Comment: I didn't say it would share the temp file name. You're not _using_ a temp file. You're using the _same file for every request_. Try the [`Path.GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) method.

Comment: in this case, how to know whats the last relevent temp file? when will i delete the temp file?

Comment: You don't need to know what the name is ahead of time. Get the name, do what you want to do with the file, delete it when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can allow multiple threads to read the file at the same time, without exception, by specifying a `FileShare` argument in [the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"E:/.../TransAlert.xml", 
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Per **Quintium**'s comment, this is the default behaviour for your code's current constructor call. Therefore, the exception is likely related to another aspect of your program. When you provide exception details, myself and/or others will be able to help you further.

**EDIT DUE TO EXCEPTION DETAILS**

The error you provided, `[IOException: The process cannot access the file 'E:\web\data\xml\TransAlert.xml' because it is being used by another process.]` indicates that the file is locked by another thread or process. In this case, the stack trace tells the story:

`System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(String inputUri, String resultsFile) +91`

Which indicates that this line is likely your problem:

`myXslTrans.Transform(@"E:/.../alert.xml", @"E:/.../TransAlert.xml");`

I believe that `Transform` will cause a WRITE operation (though I've never used it). This would be blocked by other READING operations causing this exception.

To resolve this in a quick and fairly easy fashion, you'd want to use a classic approach to file access: a spin-lock.

**Spin Locking:**

The simplest approach would be to wrap your attempt to write in a try-catch block, and if an exception is caught, sleep for X amount of time and then retry the write. This is the only "atomic" way to check for file system access.

Another common approach is to write a marker file such as "working" to the folder when you do writes. Then, check for it before letting the readers do any work (and spin-lock and check again until it is removed). The writer would remove the marker file when it is done writing, allowing the readers access once again.

Note that both writers and readers would need to be wrapped in a try-catch-spin pattern due to race conditions between checking for file access and actually accessing the file. It will not be sufficient to lock in memory on the file because if you ever go to > 1 instance of your web app, the lock will be per process instead of per file.

Comment: @Quintium you're right. How odd then. We need exception details!

Comment: @Haney the post was updated with the exception details